# Is it possible to run two Cassandra nodes in a single linux box with custom ports?

Tags: linux, cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I would like to know if it is possible to run multiple Cassandra 3.11 nodes (one is seed) in a single Linux box. The purpose can be for learning / testing.

Say I have created a directory `/data1/` for first Cassandra node, which will be `seed` node. Then I created `/data1/data/` and `/data1/logs/` directories for storing Cassandra data and logs.

Then I edited cassandra.yaml file like below;

```
cluster_name: 'Test Cluster'
hints_directory: /data/data_cassandra/hints
data_file_directories:
    - /data/data_cassandra/data
commitlog_directory: /data/data_cassandra/commitlog
saved_caches_directory: /data/data_cassandra/saved_caches
seed_provider:
    - class_name: org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider
      parameters:
          - seeds: "192.168.0.2"
storage_port: 7000
ssl_storage_port: 7001
listen_address: 192.168.0.2
broadcast_address: 192.168.0.2
native_transport_port: 9042
rpc_address: 0.0.0.0
rpc_port: 9160
broadcast_rpc_address: 192.168.0.2
endpoint_snitch: SimpleSnitch
```

This works well and my Cassandra node 1 will come up.

Then I created a directory `/data2/` for first Cassandra node, which will be `seed` node. Then I created `/data2/data/` and `/data2/logs/` directories for storing Cassandra node 2 data and logs.

Is it possible to create a yaml file to make my second Cassandra node up and running? Let's say changing port `7000` of node 2 to `7010`. Is this supported?

How can I run two Cassandra nodes in a single Linux box?

Comment: A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to [DBA Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra). For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

For running multiple nodes on a single server I would look at using the cass-operator / [k8ssandra](https://k8ssandra.io/) which will handle it for you. Cassandra 4 would handle multiple running nodes on a single OS (without virtualization in some form) but 3.11 will not.

Using docker / k8s running a 3 node cluster locally is easy and will be suitable to learn on.

Given 3.11 will soon be out of community support with the release of Cassandra 5, I would recommend using Cassandra 4.1 at this time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can definitely deploy multiple instances of Cassandra on a single OSI by assigning different ports.

The three ports you are mainly concerned with are:

- gossip port for private internode communication
- JMX port for monitoring and admin access
- CQL client port

The general practice is to assign the following numbering system for the first node in `cassandra.yaml`:

```
storage_port: 7100
native_transport_port: 9041
```

and in `cassandra-env.sh`:

```
JMX_PORT="7199"
```

For the second node:

```
storage_port: 7200
native_transport_port: 9042
```

```
JMX_PORT="7199"
```

and so on.

If you have encryption enabled, then use:

- `7101`, `7201`, and so on for gossip
- `9141`, `9142` and so on for CQL clients

If you are still using Thrift then set `rpc_port` to `9161`, `9162` and so on. Otherwise don't start the RPC server so you don't have to worry about `rpc_port`.

I would also echo @Andrew's suggestion to deploy [K8ssandra](https://k8ssandra.io/) so that it will handle all this for you but it can be a bit challenging if you have zero knowledge of Docker containers and Kubernetes clusters. Cheers!